# Reference, homage, realism, scientific-accuracy

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

What is the difference between a [reference](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) and an [homage](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homage)? Both these tags lack descriptions and there is very likely considerable overlap between them.

Similarly, what is the difference between [realism](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/realism) and [scientific-accuracy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientific-accuracy)? These two tags do have descriptions. But they don't really explain when to use which.

Comment: I'm thinking tag merge.

Comment: @TylerShads Works for me.

Comment: (I should probably clarify that @TylerShads doesn't actually work for me :P)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I for myself totally agree with your arguments and they should be merged. In my opinion `reference` and `realism` are the more apprpriate tag names respectively, since they are the more general ones.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me.  I agree that the more general term is better - "homage" is a difficult thing to define accurately.

Comment: I have removed [tag:scientific-accuracy] tag from  my question and now it can be burned. Homage and reference are little different term to me. But still i thin keeping reference will be a good idea as homage is a little complicated term.

Comment: @AnkitSharma An hommage is always a special kind of reference.

Comment: @ChristianRau agreed. I think we should act on it.

Comment: If you keep "homage" then homage questions will need tags for both reference and homage in order to be properly searchable. Otherwise a person searching for reference type questions will need to know to search on both terms.

Comment: @MaryJoFinch Fixed already anyway, according to your and my answer (and *Ankit*'s and *iandotkelly*'s affirmations).

Answer (score 3):

Reference is a broader term than homage. An homage is a reference that pays tribute or somehow honors its source. A reference can be an homage, but it can also be neutral or even negative (as in satire or parody). Therefore the tag "reference" would include homages, and the tag "homage" could go away.